# dplyr group_by and mutate, how to access the data frame?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

When using dplyr's "group_by" and "mutate", if I understand correctly, the data frame is split in different sub-dataframes according to the group_by argument. For example, with the following code :

```
 set.seed(7)
 df <- data.frame(x=runif(10),let=rep(letters[1:5],each=2))
 df %>% group_by(let) %>% mutate(mean.by.letter = mean(x))
```

mean() is applied successively to the column x of 5 sub-dfs corresponding to a letter between a & e.

So you can manipulate the columns of the sub-dfs but can you access the sub-dfs themselves ? To my surprise, if I try :

```
 set.seed(7)
 data <- data.frame(x=runif(10),let=rep(letters[1:5],each=2))
 data %>% group_by(let) %>% mutate(mean.by.letter = mean(.$x))
```

the result is different. From this result, one can infer that the "." df doesn't represent successively the sub-dfs but just the "data" one (the group_by function doens't change anything).
The reason is that I want to use a stat function that take a data frame as an arguments on each of this sub-dfs.
Thanks !

Comment: You could try with `?do`

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$let), myfun))`

Comment: I don't understand the question since the accepted answer produces the same as `data %>% group_by(let) %>% mutate(mean.by.letter = mean(x))` (unless I'm missing something) but will likely be slower because of the extra `do`-call

Comment: @docendo-discimus : sorry, if it wasn't clear but I didn't want to make it too long, so I used an over simplified exemple. And, you're right, in this simple case, I could have the simpler solution (ie the one that you repeat). But as I tried to explain in the end of my question, it is not possible to use the same solution once you need to the whole sub-dataframes as an argument of your stat function (and not just one of their column like with the x in mean()...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use within `do`

```
data %>%
    group_by(let ) %>% 
    do(mutate(., mean.by.letter = mean(.$x)))
```

Comment: @Franck : Thanks Akrun & Frank, it works fine! I used the function "do" in my solution but not the mutate one and that what was missing ! I have to say I am a bit puzzled by the "why". Do you know any advanced papers / books on how things work behind the scene ? Do you have any explanations ?

Comment: @godot  it needs a data.frame output within the `do`.  So, if you are not using `mutate`, it needs a `data.frame` call explicitly inside `do`, but it will give you only a single value per each group i.e. summarise..

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it is not the `do()` part that I don't understand, it is the "dot" part in the `mutate()` function of my 1st exemple : how come _the output of group_by (so the "." of `mutate`) is the same data.frame as its input_ ? And how does `mean()` "knows" that the var x is the column of the sub-dfs and not the main one ?

Comment: @godot the `.` is selecting the data.frame as such and `mutate` create the new column `mean.by.letter` by taking the `mean` of the extracted column 'x'

Comment: Sorry but it is still not what I am looking for... Mind if I try a last time ? :) Compare the last line of my second line of code `mutate(mean.by.letter = mean(.$x))` and your solution `do(mutate(., mean.by.letter = mean(.$x)))`... In the 1st case, `mean()` will be calculated once over the x column of data and in the 2nd one, `mean()` will be calculated on the submatrix split by letter (or so it appears at least because the result is the mean by letter). So I want to understand where the difference comes from... Sorry if I am not clear and I hope you can help me. Thank you !

Comment: @godot The difference I guess is that in the first case, you are extracting the column 'x' from the "data" i.e. `mean(.$x)` is literally similar to `mean(data$x)` which doesn't take into account the subdataset split whereas in the `do` envrionment, when you are doing `mean(.$x)` the `.` is the subdataset and `.$x` is the column extracted from subdf.

Comment: Thanks, that what I guessed... Also, the expression do environment is interesting... Never heard before, is it yours ? Btw, if you have any book/video/article on this topic, please feel free to share !

Comment: It's recommended to use `pick` now

Answer (score 3):

Since *dplyr 0.8* you can use `group_map`, the `.` in the `group_map` call will represent the sub-data.frame. Its behavior has changed a bit with time, with *dplyr 1.0* we can do

```r
df <- data.frame(x=runif(10),let=rep(letters[1:5],each=2))
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df %>%   
  group_by(let) %>%
  group_map(~mutate(., mean.by.letter = mean(x)), .keep = TRUE) %>%  
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>         x let   mean.by.letter
#>     <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
#>  1 0.442  a              0.271
#>  2 0.0999 a              0.271
#>  3 0.669  b              0.343
#>  4 0.0167 b              0.343
#>  5 0.908  c              0.575
#>  6 0.242  c              0.575
#>  7 0.685  d              0.378
#>  8 0.0716 d              0.378
#>  9 0.883  e              0.843
#> 10 0.804  e              0.843
```

`group_map()` was introduced there (with now outdated behavior!):

https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/02/dplyr-0-8-0/
https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/12/dplyr-0-8-0-release-candidate/

Comment: Thx! Could you add a link to the doc explaining that ?

Answer (score 0):

`pick` is a pretty way of doing it

```
df %>% 
  group_by(let) %>% 
  mutate(mean.by.letter = pick(everything())$x) # pick(x)$x would work too
```

### Benchmark of the solutions

`pick` is the fastest among the solutions suggested

```r
df <- data.frame(x=runif(10),let=rep(letters[1:5],each=2))

library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  pick = df %>% group_by(let) %>% mutate(mean.by.letter = pick(everything())$x),
  do = df %>% group_by(let) %>% do(mutate(., mean.by.letter = mean(.$x))),
  group_map = df %>% group_by(let) %>% group_map(~mutate(., mean.by.letter = mean(x)), .keep = TRUE) %>% bind_rows()
)

Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
      pick 103.5556 116.7587 138.3514 127.5606 148.2340 375.0288   100
        do 245.7979 280.4712 312.2932 296.6024 330.4131 595.4752   100
 group_map 257.5084 284.3772 319.6941 305.5097 325.6999 638.7950   100
```