# Which.max not working but which.min is (in R)

Tags: r, function, dplyr, max

I have a table with a list of transactions across a range of different campaigns (or projects). What I'm trying to do is derive when each campaign was started based on the day of the first transaction in each. The data covers all transactions across all campaigns with only following two columns being relevant: Campaign.ID (numeric), Created.At (yyyy-mm-dd). This is what I have at the moment:

```
temp$Recency = as.integer(today() - temp$Created.At) # Get number of days ago
df = temp %>% # Multiple transactions per user - we only need the most recent
  group_by(Campaign.ID) %>% # Group transactions together by campaign
  slice(which.max(temp$Recency)) # Find first transaction - ie biggest Recency value
df = as.data.frame(df)
```

So I create the `temp$Recency` column to change the date column to an integer of days from today. I then group the data based on their campaign ID and try to select only the first transaction for each ie. the one with the largest value in `temp$Recency`

What's puzzling me is that this code works fine if I use `which.min` for finding the last transaction of each campaign and returns a data frame with a single (most recent) instance for each campaign. Yet when I try it with `which.max` it returns an empty data frame.

I don't understand the reason for this, surely if `which.min` works as expected then `which.max` should too. I've tried searching for an answer but haven't come across anyone with the same issue.

---

The data looks something like this:

```
Created.At Campaign.ID Recency
2018-06-21        1883      13
2018-06-21        1890      13
2018-06-20        1883      14
```

There are about ~3000 records across 50-60 different campaigns

which.min returns something like this:

```
Created.At Campaign.ID Recency
2017-07-02          19     367
2017-05-25          91     405
2017-06-06         344     393
2017-06-30         451     369
2017-06-30         509     369
2017-08-16         551     322
```

I need the same thing but for `which.max`

Comment: Please show us your data.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @LAP sorry, have a few rows up now

Comment: Both `which.min` and `which.max` work for me with `df %>%
  group_by(Campaign.ID) %>%
  slice(which.max(Recency))` with the data you provided.

Comment: You don't help when you roll back all the formatting I made to your post to make it more readable...

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper sorry, I didn't mean to do that bit new to this

Comment: @LAP that actually works for me too. I had to just put in Recency instead of temp$Recency. Still don't understand why temp$Recency doesn't work or why which.min functioned fine but either way thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `temp$` from your `slice()` call.

As it is, `which.max(temp$Recency)` will return the index of the maximum value in the entire data (not one for each `Campaign.ID`), which then is out of bounds for any of the individual groups defined by `Campaign.ID` (I'm surprised this doesn't throw an error).

The expression in `slice()` is evaluated in the context of the data. However, as your data don't contain a column called `temp`, when the call is evaluated, `temp$Recency` gets found in the global environment instead. As a result, the code that you have is equivalent to:

```
max_row <- which.max(temp$Recency)
temp %>% 
  group_by(Campaign.ID) %>% 
  slice(max_row)
```

Then any groups with less than `max_row` observations just get left out.

However, if you write `slice(which.max(Recency))`, then `Recency` is found as a column in the, now grouped data, and is correctly evaluated in each group.

So, to get the result you are after, just write:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Campaign.ID) %>%
  slice(which.max(Recency))
```

as @LAP commented.

As to why `which.min` seemed to work, it's probably because the row with the global minimum is likely one of the first (maybe even the first?), so that most (if not all) of the groups have at least that many rows. I.e. if `which.min(temp$Recency) == 1` you would always just get the first row in each subgroup.

Comment: Ok this worked, thank you! And to @LAP as well. I'd still like to understand why temp$Recency doesn't work. And also why which.min seemed to be functioning fine

Comment: I edited to explain a bit further, hopefully that's helpful. Let me know if something's missing; I found it surprisingly difficult to put to words concisely.

Comment: @KevinConnell Here's also [a related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551708/dplyr-group-by-and-mutate-how-access-to-the-data-frame?noredirect=1&lq=1) with some further discussion that you may find helpful for understanding this.

Comment: Ahhh ok I think I get it now. Thanks so much for your help!